# Modeling Entity Relationships: One to Many

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am studying `One to Many` realationship in `Modeling Entity Relationships` following google document https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling

```
class Contact(db.Model):

    # Basic info.
    name = db.StringProperty()
    birth_day = db.DateProperty()

    # Address info.
    address = db.PostalAddressProperty()

    # The original phone_number property has been replaced by
    # an implicitly created property called 'phone_numbers'.

    # Company info.
    company_title = db.StringProperty()
    company_name = db.StringProperty()
    company_description = db.StringProperty()
    company_address = db.PostalAddressProperty()

class PhoneNumber(db.Model):
    contact = db.ReferenceProperty(Contact,
                                   collection_name='phone_numbers')
    phone_type = db.StringProperty(
        choices=('home', 'work', 'fax', 'mobile', 'other'))
    number = db.PhoneNumberProperty()



   scott = Contact(name='Scott')
    scott.put()
    PhoneNumber(contact=scott,
                phone_type='home',
                number='(650) 555 - 2200').put()
    PhoneNumber(contact=scott,
                phone_type='mobile',
                number='(650) 555 - 2201').put()
```

how do I query `(650) 555 - 2201` to get the ownwer of the number `scott`?

Answer (score 0):

You can query (650) 555 - 2201 to get the ownwer of the number scott as follows:

phone = PhoneNumber.all().filter('number =', '(650) 555 - 2201')

print '%s' % (phone.contact.name)